# Maximum number of characters used by a string representation of an integer type?

Tags: c++, c++11, integer, radix, constexpr

Given any (signed or unsigned) integer type `T` how do I best determine the maximum number of characters of its string representation (including the sign) in any `base` > 0 at compile time?

```
template <typename T>
constexpr auto getMaxLengthAsString(std::uintmax_t base)
    -> /* std::uintmax_t ??? */
{ /* ??? */ }
```

This is useful in some situations where one has to allocate the string beforehand and is not allowed to throw any exceptions during the conversion. A short example for its usefulness would be this:

```
template <typename T>
void examplePrintValue(T value) noexcept {
    constexpr static auto const maxLen = getMaxLengthAsString<T>(10);
    /* Ignoring thread safety etc to keep this example short: */
    static char buffer[maxLen + 1u];
    buffer[maxLen] = '\0';
    /* ... real conversion of value to buffer happens here ... */
    cout << buffer << endl;
}
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: you can just precalculate it and have a static array digits from sizeof() per base

Comment: Assume you came up with something.  What if your solution isn't 100% perfect?  IMO, it is dangerous to try and compute, down to the number of exact bytes, on how much to allocate.  You're playing a high-wire act.

Comment: @SergeyA Well it's easy for unsigned types, when one can just do things with `uintmax_t`. Things get far more complicated when `T` is a signed integral type and `numeric_limits<T>::min()` cannot be compared with a negation of a `uintmax_t base` in the regular manner because `-base` cannot be represented by type `T` nor `intmax_t`. Afaik the result of `-numeric_limits<T>::min()` might not even be representable in `uintmax_t`, because the standard doesn't guarantee that negations of the most negative values of the signed type can be represented using the respective unsigned type or `uintmax_t`.

Comment: `CHAR_BIT` is a macro that is defined as the number of bits in a `char`.  Never mind though, I misread the question

Comment: In the worst case (base 1) the number of characters is max(abs(`numeric_limits<T>::min()`) + 1, `numeric_limits<T>::max()`). So I guess this `constexpr` should fail to compile if this is not representable in any unsigned type.

Answer (score 0):

Given any integer of N bits, converted to radix B, you will have 1 character for the optional sign, followed by up to log<sub>B</sub>(1<<(N-1)) digits, rounded up.

If you don't have a function for log<sub>B</sub>, you can use

```
log(1<<(N-1))/log(B)
```

to convert the log<sub>10</sub> to log<sub>B</sub>.

So, e.g., an integer of 32 bits, converted to radix 8 (Octal), allows up to 1 character for sign plus log(1<<31)/log(8) == 1+10.3333 == 12 maximum characters.

As for evaluating at compile time, most modern C++ compilers support constant evaluation as well as intrinsic functions that can be evaluated at compile time if they are provably constant, which the above would be.

Answer (score 0):

For unsigned integers

1. You need to write a `constexpr` logarithm function.
2. Apply it to `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()`, then divide it by logarithm of the base.

For signed integers you just do the same thing and add one (for minus sign).